# React-Native navigate to initial screen within another stack navigator didn't show back button

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Here is my current navigation

```
MainNavigator
|--Homepage
|--MenuNavigator
   |--Menu
   |--Profile
   |--HistoryNavigator
      |--InitialScreen
      |--OtherScreen
```

I had HistoryNavigator with headerShown set to false to make its child handle their own header navigation

Then the problem is when I try to navigate to HistoryNavigator from Menu it will show the back button on its InitialScreen but when I try to navigate to HistoryNavigator from Homepage it won't show the back button on InitialScreen but when I navigate to OtherScreen from InitialScreen it shows the back button

MainNavigator

```js
<Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Homepage"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
    <Stack.Screen name="Homepage" component={Homepage} />
    <Stack.Screen name="MenuNavigator" component={MenuNavigator} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

MenuNavigator

```js
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Menu">
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          title: "Menu",
          presentation: "modal",
        }}
        name="Menu"
        component={Menu}
      />
     <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
     <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
        name="HistoryNavigator"
        component={HistoryNavigator}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

HistoryNavigator

```js
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="InitialScreen">
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          title: "Initial Screen"
        }}
        name="InitialScreen"
        component={InitialScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          title: "Other Screen",
        }}
        name="OtherScreen"
        component={OtherScreen}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

onPress to navigate from the menu

```js
onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("HistoryNavigator")
          }}
```

onPress to navigate from the homepage

```js
onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("MenuNavigator", {
                  screen: "HistoryNavigator",
                });
              }}
```

If I set headerShown=true on HistoryNavigator and false on its child then when I navigate to HistoryNavigator from Homepage and try to navigate to OtherScreen from InitialScreen if I press the header back button it will redirect me to Homepage not the InitialScreen